# Are there multiple random seeds and sequences

Tags: python, random, python-3.4, micropython

I want to make a game in micropython an implementation of python 3.4.  I want my monsters to be controlled by a random number generator. I was considering passing the current grid reference as a seed and todays date so the monster would always appear today. Play the game tomorrow and there will be new monsters.

The problem is i need to use `random.randint` and `random.randchoice` for dice and other truely random events.

If i were doing this in c I'd use `erand48` from `<stdlib.h>` and keep and maintain multiple seeds.

What are my solutions in python?

I probably need a chaotic function to control monsters. Years ago i were given one by a maths professor, but it was simple and due to floating point rounding it tended to 0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the random module of python to create random objects for each independent component. Example:

```
import random
import datetime

#to set the random number based off the date
today = str(datetime.date.today())

monster_locations = random.Random(today)
traps = random.Random((today + '1'))
```

These individual random objects each have their own independent seeds and can be called just like the regular random class:

```
monster_x = monster_locations.randInt(0,10)
trap_type = traps.randInt(0,4)
```

Comment: When i try `traps.randInt(0,4)` i get `attribute error: NoneType object has no attribute randInt` . I've tried `randint` and `randrange`

Comment: You code still doesn't  work. `random.seed(x)` returns a NoneType

Comment: Use `random.Random(seed)` to create an object you store as a variable. That variable is then where the calls to methods are made from. E.g. `a=random.Random(123); print(a.randint(0,10))`

Answer (score 1):

[The docs of `random` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) mention

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that there is *only* one random seed.
You use `getstate` and `setstate` to save and restore previous random positions.

```
import random

random.seed(1)
for _ in range(5):
    print(random.randrange(10), end = ' ')
print('')

save = random.getstate()

random.seed(1)
for _ in range(10):
    print(random.randrange(10), end = ' ')
print('')


random.setstate(save)
for _ in range(5):
    print(random.randrange(10), end = ' ')
print('')
```

produces the following output

```
2 9 1 4 1 
2 9 1 4 1 7 7 7 6 3 
7 7 7 6 3
```